# Formula to calculate angle on a fan or semicircle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

> How do I calculate the angle shown in the picture given the height, width, and the
>   arc deduction of $2$?

I had applied the Right Triangles formula to calculate the hypotenuse: $h^2 = a^2 + b^2  \implies  h^2 = 21.5^2 + 18^2 \implies h = 28.0401498$.

Then applied the Law of Sines ratio(s): $$s= \frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C}$$

so

$s=\frac{28.04015}{\sin(90)} = 28.04015 \\
\frac{c}{\sin C} = s\\
\frac{18}{\sin C} = 28.04015\\
c=\arcsin\left(\frac{18}{25.04015}\right)\\
c=39.93638....$

This is not coming to be $38.2303$ as shown in the picture.  I can't figure out where is my mistake.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: c can be calculated directly by arctan (18/21.5). But this is not the required. It is the one with the lower arc instead. The data 60.8926 provides important info in obtaining the required.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Use 60.8926 to obtain $\theta$, the semi-central angle (approximately equal to $79.21^0$).
2. Use power of a point to find R (i.e. $18(2R - 18) = 21.5^2$, such that R = 21.8427778)
3. Consider $\triangle OCG$ to find $d$. [$R - 18 = (R - d) \cos \theta$]
4. Use $\triangle KFO$ to get the required. [$\angle FKO = arctan \frac {(18 - d)}{21.5}$]